Has Voevodsky's idea of "reliable" proofs been rigorously developed and studied?
In the lecture titled What if Current Foundations of Mathematics are Inconsistent? at time 39:45   Vladimir Voevodsky talks about an idea of an algorithm which verifies "reliability" of a proof(including the possibility that proof comes from an inconsistent theory). In the next slide he briefly mentions his idea of constructing such an algorithm and says that there are probably a lot ways to do such a thing. Has this idea of "reliability" of a proof really been rigorously developed and studied somewhere and if so where can I read more about it ?
